# Speeding up simultaneous numerical integration where some integrals vanish

Tags: numerical-integration, convergence

I would like to carry out a number of numerical integrals in the form of a table:

```
Iint[\[Theta]_, \[Theta]1_] = 
  Exp[-I n \[Theta]] Exp[
    I n1 \[Theta]] (rx^2 (Cos[\[Theta]] - Cos[\[Theta]1])^2 + 
      ry^2 (Sin[\[Theta]] - Sin[\[Theta]1])^2)^m Sqrt[
    rx^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + ry^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2] Sqrt[
    rx^2 Sin[\[Theta]1]^2 + 
     ry^2 Cos[\[Theta]1]^2] (rx^2 Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]1] + 
     ry^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]1]);
Table[NIntegrate[
  Iint[\[Theta], \[Theta]1], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta]1, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}], {m, 1, 2}, {n, 0, 1}, {n1, 0, 1}]
```

I know that some of these integrals vanish. When Mathematica does these particular numerical integrals, I get the expected errors regarding convergence being too slow and the code takes a lot longer to run than the non-zero integrals e.g. the following will run very quickly:

```
m = 1;
n = 0;
n1 = 0;
NIntegrate[
  Iint[\[Theta], \[Theta]1], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta]1, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}]
```

My question is how do I run the table of numerical integrals quickly by telling Mathematica just to display zero if it's encountering convergence problems and the answer is going to be several orders of magnitude smaller than the others? Thanks in advance for any help.

Update (10/07/2020): The best I can come up with for speeding up the calculation when the integral is zero is to add on a bit to the integrand and then subtract off the corresponding amount after the integration:

```
Table[NIntegrate[
   Iint[\[Theta], \[Theta]1] + 1, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta]1, 
    0, 2 \[Pi]}] - 4 \[Pi]^2, {m, 1, 2}, {n, 0, 1}, {n1, 0, 1}]
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Try `Quiet@Check[..., 0]` ? around your `NIntegrate`

Comment: Even better, you could pick out the message you don't care about more precisely so other errors aren't suppressed: ```badmessages = {NIntegrate::inumr, NIntegrate::ncvb};
Quiet[Check[..., 0, badmessages], badmessages]```

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical case for `AccuracyGoal` (*absolute error*) and `PrecisionGoal` (*relative error*).

---

Define the integrand

```
Iint[q_, p_] = Exp[-I n q] Exp[I n1 q] 
 (rx^2 (Cos[q] - Cos[p])^2 +  ry^2 (Sin[q] - Sin[p])^2)^m 
 Sqrt[rx^2 Sin[q]^2 + ry^2 Cos[q]^2] 
 Sqrt[rx^2 Sin[p]^2 +ry^2 Cos[p]^2] 
 (rx^2 Sin[q] Sin[p] + ry^2 Cos[q] Cos[p]);
```

Now do the integrations

```
Table[NIntegrate[Iint[q, p], {q, 0, 2 Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi},
                  PrecisionGoal->Infinity, AccuracyGoal->10], 
        {m, 1, 2}, {n, 0, 1}, {n1, 0, 1}]
```

---

- With `PrecisionGoal->p` and `AccuracyGoal->a`, the Wolfram Language
  attempts to make the numerical error in a result of size $x$ be less
  than $10^{-a}+|x|10^{-p}$.
- `PrecisionGoal->Infinity` specifies that precision should not be used
  as the criterion for terminating the numerical procedure.
  `AccuracyGoal` is typically used in this case. This is what we are doing here.
- Notice that *per default* we have `AccuracyGoal->Infinity`, which means only the relative error is the stopping condition. When the integral $x\rightarrow 0$, this lead to error messages.